# Ant Macrodef attribute usage

Tags: ant, scp

I have defined a macro in ant script which takes host as parameter:

```
<macrodef name="upload">
    <attribute name="host"/>
    <sequential>
    <echo>Uploading source code to @{host}...</echo>
    <scp trust="true" 
       file="package/code.zip"
       todir="${webserver.username}@@{host}:${webserver.upload_dir}" 
       keyfile="${webserver.keyfile}"
       passphrase="" />
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Problem is I can't figure out how to use @{host} in todir string as it already has a '@' character between username and host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per : https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html ,

```
The escape sequence @@ is used to escape @. 
This allows @{x} to be placed in the text without substitution of x by using @@{x}.
```

So try with adding additional '@' prior to getting value of host attribute.

Also you could try setting `<property name="token" value="@"/>` and use it withing todir with ${token} to see if that helps